# Error in App class when using React-Redux "connect "

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am receiving the following error when trying to use the `connect()` function from `react-redux`:

```
Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.

Check the render method of `App`.
```

This is App:

```
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import configureStore from './store';
const App = class extends React.PureComponent {
  render() {
    const { title } = this.context;
    return (
      <div className="center-screen">
        {title}
        <Provider store={configureStore()}>
          <Chat />
        </Provider>
      </div>
    );
  }
};
```

This is the relevent code end of chat:

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';


  ...


    const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  ...state
});
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  addMessage: () => dispatch(addMessage)
});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(Chat);
```

When using : "export default Chat" instead of connect, it's working fine..

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
const ConnectedChat = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(Chat);

export default ConnectedChat;
```

Or you may wish to rename the class definition to ConnectedChat and reverse the names so you can import it as just Chat.

Edit: Also make sure you're importing the Chat component in the App file, as well as the addMessage action creator if you're not.

Comment: I am still getting the same error. I used the same code you posted and now app.js uses ConnectedChat instead of Chat

Comment: Hmm. Can you post the full Chat component?

Comment: I added Chat and App in here (this is a cut down version and it does nothing, but it still doesn't work here.So whatever the problem with my full component  is (that I can't fully disclose unfortunately),it's still alive in this version):https://codesandbox.io/s/lp9k07ro3m

Comment: Something is not being imported or exported properly, it's hard to tell without the entire source tree.  At a glance the statements all appear to follow proper syntax, I would double check all the routes and make sure that the capitalization and paths line up (for example, importing from "./Chat" will throw an error if the file is named "chat.js").  You may have just named it that on the sandbox for convenience, but I'd go over everything just to be sure. I was able to get the sandbox working by renaming those and removing unused references.

Answer (score 0):

Where are you defining `Chat` the component in your connect function?

My usual set up is (I'm using class but `const ConnectedChart()` would still be this same set up)

```
class ConnectedChart extends Component {

//// All code here render and return etc

}

const Chart = connect (mapStateToProps)(ConnectedChat);

export default Chart;
```

So that way you are essentially assigning a component to Chart with the connect statement and then you export default. I think exporting the connect statement directly might by throwing an error but if that doesn't work post the full chart component and I'll see if there is something else going on

---

EDIT: based on the full code

try this in your App.js:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import "./App.css";
import ConnectedChat from "./Chat";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import configureStore from "./store";

ReactDOM.render(
        <Provider store={configureStore()}>
          <ConnectedChat />
        </Provider>
    );
```

and then put your div center screen in ConnectedChat

(if you are going to be adding more components later and want that div wrapping all of them, create a main app component like landing or something and call that between your provider instead of chat, and then in that landing component render the div and your ChatComponent)

Also if you don't have an index.js change the 'main' in your package.json to this App.js component

Comment: I added Chat and App in here (this is a cut down version and it does nothing, but it still doesn't work here.So whatever the problem with my full component is (that I can't fully disclose unfortunately),it's still alive in this version):https://codesandbox.io/s/lp9k07ro3m

Comment: Do you have an index.js in your src directory, or is App.js your base file that is rendering everything else?

If App is your base file, I think the problem is how you are rendering it.

Comment: I added some stuff above with new suggestions

Comment: Where should I put the "ReactDOM.render" ? in the return method of App ?. And yes there is an index.js file that uses App.js

Comment: React DOM.render should go in your index or whatever your most root file is, because it can only have one child component and that child component (usually called App.js) is the parent of all other components in your application. So what I wrote above with the configure store and reactDOM.render that should all be in that root react file whatever it's called (usually index)